# I am trying to do pagination in flask without html?Can anyone explain the process?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my flask code for pagination and when i posted the url there 
   was error messages showing like

start_copy = max(1, start - limit)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'pagination' and 'str'
 help me to solve this error!!

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request, jsonify


from models import Categories

from flask_restful import Resource

app = Flask(__name__)

class pagination(Resource):

    url= '/getbypages'
    start=1
    limit=20
    def get(start,limit):
        results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        print("resultsllllllllllll",results)
        count = len(results)
        obj = {}
        if count < 1:
            print("404")
        else:
            #count = limit-start
            #print(count)
            obj['start'] = start
            obj['limit'] = limit
            obj['count'] = count
            print(obj)
            if start == 1:
                obj['previous'] = ''
            else:
                start_copy = max(1, start - limit)
                print(start_copy)
                limit_copy = start - 1
                obj['previous'] = url + '?start=%d&limit=%d' % (start_copy, limit_copy)
                if start + limit > count:
                    obj['next'] = ''
                else:
                    start_copy = start + limit
                    obj['results'] = results[(start - 1):(start - 1 + limit)]
        return obj
    print(get(start, limit))
```

Comment: start_copy = max(1, start - limit)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'pagination' and 'str'
getting this error

Comment: please read [ask] and improve your question